# Problemas con la creacion de una tabla temporal

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

1.Estoy teniendo un inconveniente con el código ya que cuando utilizo el select para llamar la tabla temporal me salta este error Error: Table 'temporales.tpmcon' doesn't exist.

Codigo:

```
<?php 
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","temporales");

$temp="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tpmcon(
    id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_ciudad VARCHAR(10),
    nombre_paises VARCHAR(10)";
mysqli_query($conn,$temp);
$insert="INSERT INTO tpmcon(nombre_ciudad, nombre_paises)
VALUES('New York', 'USA'),('Madrid', 'España')";
mysqli_query($conn, $insert);  

$query = "SELECT * FROM tpmcon";

if ($res=mysqli_query($conn,$query) )
{ $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); } 
else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);}

?>
```

Comment: Deberías añadir el error que te sale en la pregunta, porque ahora mismo no se entiende el problema que tienes.

Comment: Además, deberías dejar de mezclar tanto php y html, en vez de cerrar y abrir los tags de php para poner tr y td, simplemente usa echo "<td>$row['id_ciudad']</td>";. Nadie te impide meter tags html en un echo de php, además si es un echo con comillas dobles podrás llamar a las variables dentro sin concatenar ni nada.

Comment: ¿A qué se debe el `¿` en el nombrado de la tabla:  `SELECT * FROM  ¿tpmcon`? Luego, las columnas se llaman `id` y `nombre_paises` en el CREATE TABLE, pero en la lectura estás usando: `id_ciudad` y `nombre_paise`. ¿Es un error de typo  al escribir la pregunta o falta de rigor al escribir tu código?

Comment: Muchas gracias, por responder pude quitar organizar el codigo y dejarlo mas limpio y funcional, Use este codigo de php para identificar el error  if ($res=mysqli_query($conn,$query) )
{ $fila=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res); } 
else { echo "Error: ".mysqli_error($conn);} Caundo lo utilize me salta este mensaje pero no entiendo por que sale o que estoy haceindo mal Error: Table 'temporales.tpmcon' doesn't exist me puedes colaborar porfavor Actualize el codigo anterior y coloque uno nuevo

Comment: ¿Existe la base de datos "temporales"? ¿porqué creas la tabla tmpcon como TEMPORARY?

Comment: Si temporales es la base de datos y tpmcon es la tabla temporal que quiero crear desde el codigo,la tabla tmpcon la creo temporal para que cuando se cierre la sesion los datos que vayan aqui se eliminen y no ocupe espacio

Comment: ¿Y si creas un array? siempre será más rápido que una tabla temporal.

Comment: Alguien tiene un código php que trabaje con  tablas temporales para que lo comparta por favor.